# How to add picture into database?

Tags: oracle, vb6

I have created a table mypics that contains one column of BLOB datatype.

Now I need to implement a vb6 code to Select/Insert/Update data in this table, but I don`t know how to deal with the BLOB column...

SQL> desc mypics
 Name                                                  Null?    Type

---

PID                                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(38)

PNAME                                                         CHAR(10)

IMAGE                                                         BLOB

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some example code to get you started. Assume a table named tblImages with 3 fields.

```
Field       Data Type     Size
Picture         Image          
ID              Int            4
```

To add an image from a file on disk to the database

```
Set strStream = New ADODB.Stream
strStream.Type = adTypeBinary
strStream.Open
strStream.LoadFromFile strFileName

strSQL = "SELECT ID, Picture FROM tblImages"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Source = strSQL 
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open
End With

rs.AddNew   
rs.Fields("ID").Value = ID
rs.Fields("Picture").Value = strStream.Read
rs.Update
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

To extract the file from database to a disk file :

```
strSQL = "SELECT Picture FROM tblImages WHERE ID = " & ID               
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Source = strSQL
    .Open
End With

If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    Set strStream = New ADODB.Stream
    strStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    strStream.Open    
    strStream.Write rs!Picture
    strStream.SaveToFile TempPath, adSaveCreateOverWrite        
    strStream.Close
    Set strStream = Nothing        
End If    
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

I hope this helps.